# PyMongo set log level

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I would like to set the log level of various components in the mongodb.conf file by running a .py script. I usually just use basic commands agains the database like update_one or insert with no problems. The error I am getting:

"TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'setloglevel' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.

I've tried setLogLevel; set_log_level and a few others. Cannot fine anything in pymongo documentation or online.

How do I set log level and is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
def setlvl():

## Connection to the Mongo Service ##

  try:
      conn=pymongo.MongoClient("myip_address")
      print("Connected successfully!!!")
  except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure:
     print("Could not connect to MongoDB: %s" % e )

  print("Connection:",conn)

## Connect to the DataBase ##

  db = conn.mydatabase
  print("database:", db)      

## Update log level ##

  loglvl = db.setloglevel
  result=loglvl(5, "storage")

setlvl()
```

Answer (score 2):

"setLogLevel" is a mongo shell function implemented in Javascript. You can see the implementation of any mongo shell function by typing its name in the mongo shell, without parentheses:

```
> db.setLogLevel
function (logLevel, component) {
    return this.getMongo().setLogLevel(logLevel, component);
}
```

OK, so let's go deeper and really see the implementation:

```
> db.getMongo().setLogLevel
function (logLevel, component) {
    componentNames = [];
    if (typeof component === "string") {
        componentNames = component.split(".");
    } else if (component !== undefined) {
        throw Error("setLogLevel component must be a string:" + tojson(component));
    }
    var vDoc = {verbosity: logLevel};

    // nest vDoc
    for (var key, obj; componentNames.length > 0;) {
        obj = {};
        key = componentNames.pop();
        obj[key] = vDoc;
        vDoc = obj;
    }
    var res = this.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, logComponentVerbosity: vDoc});
    if (!res.ok)
        throw _getErrorWithCode(res, "setLogLevel failed:" + tojson(res));
    return res;
}
```

Now we see the shell runs the "setParameter" function on the admin database. See the setParameter docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setParameter/

Since "setParameter" is a MongoDB command, we can run it in PyMongo the same way we run any MongoDB command with PyMongo:

```
from bson import SON

from pymongo import MongoClient

c = MongoClient()

result = c.admin.command(SON([
    ("setParameter", 1),
    ("logComponentVerbosity", {
        "storage": {
            "verbosity": 5,
            "journal": {
                "verbosity": 1
            }
        }
    })]))

print(result)
```